# iTextSharp NET Remove spacing between cells

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I'm trying to add three cells in one row, which have colored background with the same color. The problem is that I see space (or vertical border) between these cells, but I don't need this space.

[image: Result row image]

As you can see on the image, there is some space. Maybe this is the wrong way to do what I need. I need this green text in the center of page and white text on the right side at the same row and with the same background color.

This is my code:

```
    PdfPCell emptyCell = new PdfPCell();
    emptyCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
    emptyCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
    emptyCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    emptyCell.MinimumHeight = 30f;
    emptyCell.Colspan = 3;
    emptyCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    _currentTable.AddCell(emptyCell);

    iTextSharp.text.Font clubFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.NORMAL, new BaseColor(0.541f, 0.765f, 0f));
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph clubName = new Paragraph(clubString, clubFont) {Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER};
    cell.AddElement(clubName);
    cell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
    cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
    cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell.MinimumHeight = 30f;
    cell.Colspan = _currentTable.NumberOfColumns - 6;
    cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    _currentTable.AddCell(cell);

    iTextSharp.text.Font dispFont = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.WHITE);
    PdfPCell dispCell = new PdfPCell();
    Paragraph dispersion = new Paragraph(dispersionString, dispFont);
    dispersion.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    dispCell.AddElement(dispersion);
    dispCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
    dispCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    dispCell.MinimumHeight = 30f;
    dispCell.Colspan = 3;
    dispCell.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.DARK_GRAY;
    dispCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
    _currentTable.AddCell(dispCell);
```